# Fixed Facebook Page Like Button

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, facebook-like

I am looking for a Script to show Facebook Page Like Button Similar to the one at

http://www.go2web20.net/twitterFollowBadge/

Any Pointers?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by fixed?

Comment: By Fixed I mean: The Button should be at the left or right of your window, When you Scroll it should not move.

Comment: ok, you should add that to your question, and add tags css, javascript, coz i believe that's what is making it fixed. So that people in those tags will see the question and can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do it:

- configure the like widget as you want it at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/
- include the js SDK as per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
- add css similar to my example at http://jsfiddle.net/ecmanaut/paVeG/

All modern browsers will happily rotate it to sit on its side, if you want it to look that way (if not, remove the transform stuff). I don't think Facebook lets you make it look exactly however you want it to, if that's an important aspect, but there are other questions dealing with overriding that anyway, if important. (People are probably more prone to use this thing if they recognize its looks and functionality from all over the web anyway.)

Comment: I've edited ecmanaut's fiddle. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paVeG/3/). You can see, likebox is fixed even at page scroll. :)